# supabase bucket getPublicUrl returns url that doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, supabase, bucket, supabase-js

I'm using the supabase js API to create a public bucket and upload images to it.
This works so far:

```
const { data: bucket, error } = await supabase.storage.createBucket(
        bucketName,
        {
          public: true,
        }
      );

//// map an array of files

const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
              .from(bucketName)
              .upload(filename, file, {
                cacheControl: "3600",
                upsert: false,
              });
```

I can see the files uploaded correctly in the supabase console but I can't display them on my project. I get the url but it doesn't show, and when i enter that link direclty in the navigator I get an error of "object not found"

```
 const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.listBuckets(
        order.bucketId
      );
      let files = [];
      data.map((file) => {
        const { data, error } = supabase.storage
          .from(order.bucketId)
          .getPublicUrl(file.name);
        files.push(data.publicUrl);
      });
```

I don't understand what's wrong. I gave all permissions in the buckets policies and also tried using a private bucket, but it also gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be fetching the list of buckets instead of list of files in the bucket. You can use the [list()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-list) method to get the list of files in your bucket.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from(order.bucketId).list('/path/to/your/files');
      let files = [];
      data.map((file) => {
        const { data, error } = supabase.storage
          .from(order.bucketId)
          .getPublicUrl(file.name);
        files.push(data.publicUrl);
      });
```